# How to prevent inline-block from wrapping when the inline-block content is very long

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When the red text of the inline-block is short, it is displayed normally. But when the red text of the inline-block exceeds the length of the screen or the content is too long, the red text will be displayed in a line break with other text. The result I want is that when the red text is too long, there is no need to wrap.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<span>green and</span>
<span style='color:red; display:inline-block;vertical-align:top'>blue, green and blue Pink，purple, <span style="border-top:1px solid blue;red:red;display:block">Text annotation</span> </span> orange, black and white, Pink，purple, orange, black and white, stand up, sit down, turn around. Pink，purple, orange, black and white.3. BingoThere was a farmer had a dog, and bingo was h 
<span>day friday Saturdaysunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday Saturday6. Little pigOink oink little pig Oink oink oink little pig Oink oink little pig Oink oink oink little pig7. I ‘m hungryI'm a little hungry,I'm hungry.Have som</span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n40Vu.png)

Comment: it's not clear at all what you want. can you share a screenshot of the intended result, not the problematic one

Comment: Thank you . I have share a result screenshot.

Comment: give use the result you want when there is a wrap, what you are showing actually is an inline-block configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly this is what you're asking for, wrap your text inside a `<p>` tag and it won't be separated

```css
.long-text {
color : red;
}
```

```html
<p class="container">
green and
<span class="long-text">blue, green and blue Pink，purple, orange, black and white, Pink，purple, orange, black and white, stand up, sit down, turn around. Pink，purple, orange, black and white.3. BingoThere was a farmer had a dog, and bingo was h</span>
day friday Saturdaysunday monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday Saturday6. Little pigOink oink little pig Oink oink oink little pig Oink oink little pig Oink oink oink little pig7. I ‘m hungryI'm a little hungry,I'm hungry.Have som
</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

As you said, you only need to add a container to wrap the content.